# How to autostart xen guests after power failure

Tags: xen

I have an Ubuntu server running xen (with xen-tools only) and when the server experiences a power failure I have to manually run `xl create /etc/xen/MY_DOMU_GUEST.cfg` to restart the vm.

My config settings for restarting look like this:

`/etc/xen/MY_DOMU_GUEST.cfg`:

```
on_poweroff = 'restart'
on_reboot   = 'restart'
on_crash    = 'restart'
```

But it doesn't start on dom0 boot. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/196444/how-do-i-auto-start-xen-guests-on-boot/906499#906499

## The Short Answer

To load all config files on boot link the `auto` folder directly to `/etc/xen`:

```
ln -s /etc/xen/ /etc/xen/auto
```

To load only specific config files link each individually:

```
mkdir -p /etc/xen/auto
ln -s /etc/xen/MY_DOMU_GUEST_1.cfg /etc/xen/auto/
ln -s /etc/xen/MY_DOMU_GUEST_2.cfg /etc/xen/auto/
```

## Explanation

There's a lesser-known `xen` config file `/etc/default/xendomains`.

There you can find in the comments documentation for three default settings:

```
XENDOMAINS_SAVE=/var/lib/xen/save
XENDOMAINS_RESTORE=true
XENDOMAINS_AUTO=/etc/xen/auto
```

To summarize the docs:

- `XENDOMAINS_SAVE` causes the VMs to be saved on a proper `reboot`.
- `XENDOMAINS_RESTORE` causes the VMs to be brought back up from the saved state when saved (whether saved manually with `xl save` or due to host reboot).
- `XENDOMAINS_AUTO` specifies a folder from which to load configs for VMs when no save state exists (i.e. `XENDOMAINS_SAVE` is disabled or there was a power failure or explicit `shutdown` instead of a `reboot`)

If you create the `auto` folder under `/etc/xen` and give it symlinks to the config file of the virtual machine (DomU guest) you'd like to start on physical machine (Dom0 host) then generally speaking they'll restore from the saved state that happens during the physical (host) server on reboot, but when that isn't available (such as after a shutdown or power failure or crash), they'll still load anyway.

If you'd rather always have the VMs shutdown on reboot rather than save state you can set `XENDOMAINS_SAVE=` and `XENDOMAINS_RESTORE=false`.

## The Old Way

It used to be that where there is now `on_shutdown`, `on_reboot`, and `on_crash` that you could also configure `on_xend_start = 'start'` and
`on_xend_stop = 'shutdown'`... but those are not the current practice.

Current (apply to the VM state itself):

```
on_shutdown = 'destroy'
on_reboot = 'restart'
on_crash = 'restart'
```

Ignored / Deprecated (apply to the host state):

```
on_xend_start = 'start'
on_xend_stop = 'shutdown'
```

Comment: If the auto start doesn't always work, where do I find the code that executes the order, they start? I have this problem: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/586150/20661

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old post but there is an easier way.

Create a script MyScripNameHere.sh in this script add the following syntax, and add appropriate permissions to execute as root.

#!/bin/bash

export PATH=/opt/xensource/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr

sleep 60

xe vm-start vm="VMNAMEHERE1"

sleep 5

xe vm-start vm="VMNAMEHERE2"

Then add the path to the script in rc.local , however before execution add sleep 60
This will autostart all the VM in the script list. This is if you do not want to deal with UUID or pooling.

Comment: I'd argue that creating symlinks where xen expects them is, in fact, easier than creating an rc file with sleeps.