# How to stop auto-rebooting of xen-domain?

Tags: xen

I want to terminate a xen-domain named `xyz`. I'm doing so by executing `sudo xl shutdown xyz` (also tried `destroy`). The domain is shutdown normally - but it's getting rebooted every time and I don't understand why.

The link to the domains config-file in `/etc/xen/auto` is already deleted (like described [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/845196/how-to-autostart-xen-guests-after-power-failure)). What can additionally lead to such a behaviour and how can I stop it?

xen_version is 4.4.1.
In `/etc/default/xendomains` the following is set:

```
XENDOMAINS_SAVE=""
XENDOMAINS_RESTORE=true
XENDOMAINS_AUTO=/etc/xen/auto
```